# I want to count the number based on a field injected

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I am working on SSRS report.
I have a report where the user inserts the login, start date and end date.
I want to count the number of rows of WarantyColumn that have the value 1 for the user injected between start date and end date.

```
Count(iif(Fields!TextField.Value=, Fields!TextField.Value, Nothing))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I advise you read the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article as it provides very useful information for newcomers on how to write questions. Quality questions help us provide you quality answers - Please format your question for better readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new column, let's call it `warrantycolumncount`. For this column, set expression as

```
IIF(Field!warrantycolumn.Value = 1, 1, 0)
```

This expression will set 1 where your condition matches and 0 where condition does not match.

If you wish you can hide this column for you final report as well

Now at the bottom of your tablix you can create row Total

To add totals for a row group

- In the tablix data region row group area, right-click a cell in the row group area for which you want totals, point to Add Total, and then click Before or After. A new row outside the current group is added to the data region, and then a default total is added for each numeric field in the row.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to use something like.

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!WarrantyColumn.Value = 1,1,0))
```

This will work inside a tablix that is bound to your dataset. If you need to do the same outside of the tablix then you have to provide scope, so something like.

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!WarrantyColumn.Value = 1,1,0), "myDatasetName")
```

**Note: ** oy must put the dataset name in quotes and it is case sensitive so it must match the name exactly.