# add header title to the groups in Microsoft reporting

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am very new to Microsoft reporting. I have a table and I need to show the Category Name and the count how many times the category existed in the report so for e.g, I have the following:

```
CategoryName    Id

Normal          1
High            2
Normal          3
Low             4
Normal          5
Normal          6
Normal          7
Normal          8
Low             9
Low             10
Low             11
High            12
```

I want to display something like this:

```
Category   Count

    Normal  6
    Low     4
    High    2
```

I was able to display the category ( Normal, Low and High) and the associated count with the category. The problem is, I cannot put the title "Category" and "count" at the top because I put the CategoryName and count in the header column and I deleted the data column like I showed in the image below. How can I put the title in the above table.

The image after adding the group filed looks like this:

[image]

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Problem:
Category and Count as Title of your Tablix.

It's pretty easy. Just go to you Header Click on Cell where you wish to put Category.
You can write Category just like a TextBox

[image]

Comment: My Category and name is not in the data section, it is in Header section so in other words where the Header "Ttle" supposed to be, I have Grouping of Category Name so there is no space for Title.

Comment: What do you mean by no space?? But category name and  count does come from your dataset?? You mentioned in Question your desired output and you do get category name and count group by category. It’s just the title for table??

Comment: Yes Category Name and count comes from the Dataset. when I group by Category Name, I put it in Header section and Put the count of categoryName in Header section too and I delete the Data section cells completely. I am going to post the image above.

Comment: I posted the image above

Comment: Ahh got that. You don’t need to add group made up of category name into header. You can leave it in normal row. Now you will have your header left empty. By grouping on record level will still give you desired results

Comment: If I do that, I get lot of empty rows

Comment: Alright do something like this. Add one more column let’s call it Count Dumy. Now for this column add expression into row as IIF(isnothing(Field!categoryname.value),0,1)        What this will do is in new column set 1 where there is category name and if no category name then 0. Now you do nothing but just group your row with category name. This will give you exact results. Here is one of my answer for similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/55747068/5436880

Comment: Thank You. I figured out while replying to your message. Thanks again!